# Is there a way get a fighter jet on demand?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I ask the question because it seems like I saw someone do this.  I was in a helicopter and picked a fight with someone on the ground (tried to drop a car on him).  Within a few moments a fighter jet appeared over the garage he was hiding in.  It proceeded to blow me out of the sky (no problem with that, I had it coming).  We were nowhere near the military base.

Is there some way to keep a jet in a garage or order one up (i.e., from Merriweather or Lester).  I looked and can't see any option like that.

Comment: Maybe they purchased it online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At level 50, you can Merryweather and for $12,500 you can throw a flare to designate an area for an airstrike.  There is no way for a player to have a jet ready on demand for their own use though.

Comment: Well... you could try to steal one in the Army base hehe

Comment: It's not too hard to get a jet from the military base in the online mode.

Comment: Once upon a time there was bug with the Top Fun mission that let you get into the base without stars.  They've since patched it and now it's near impossible to get away with any jet not inside a hanger.